# Which is the Method Key Derivation (MKD) for Cryptogram version 5

Tags: cryptography, emv

I am developing a software for EMV transactions and I am facing a huge lack of documentation from the company who has hired me.
One of them is about the MKD for generating the ARQC (during the first GENERATE AC). I know from the message request that the IAD is as below:

> *0FA501A030F8000000000000000000000F000000000000000000000000000000*

According to it the Cryptogram Version is 5, but I have no idea about the MKD.

Does anyone who has been involved in this subject know something about the MKD I should use to generate ARQC ?

I´d appreciate any comments.
Thanks.

Comment: When in doubt, reference the (EMV) standard.

Comment: Hi @MaartenBodewes, I did as you suggested me and it worked. The MDK follows EMV 4.2 standard. Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad that worked out for you!

Answer (score 2):

(In context of vanilla EMV and Common Core Specifications)

Citing [EMV 4.3](https://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223), Book 2, section 8.1.2:

> The method for Application Cryptogram generation takes as input a
>   unique  ICC Application Cryptogram Master Key MKAC and the data
>   selected as  described in section 8.1.1, and computes the 8-byte
>   Application Cryptogram in the following two steps:
>
> 1. Use the session key derivation function specified in Annex A1.3 to derive  an Application Cryptogram Session Key SKAC from the ICC
>      Application  Cryptogram Master Key MKAC and the 2-byte Application
>      Transaction  Counter (ATC) of the ICC.
> 2. Generate the 8-byte Application Cryptogram by applying the MAC  algorithm specified in Annex A1.2 to the data selected and using the 
>      Application Cryptogram Session Key derived in the previous step. For 
>      AES the 8-byte Application Cryptogram is created by setting the 
>      parameter s to 8.

The MKAC itself is derived from 'Issuer (Application Cryptogram) Master Key' (section 8.3):

> For a cryptogram defined by the Common Core Definitions with a
>   Cryptogram  Version of '5', the ICC Master Key shall be derived using
>   the Option B method  described in Annex A1.4.2.

See the mentioned annexes of EMV Book 2 for detailed descriptions.

I can provide the following java code (semi-tested but without any guarantees):

```
public static byte[] deriveMasterKey(byte[] issuerMasterKey, byte[] pan, byte[] panSequenceNumber) {
    String concat;
    if(((pan[pan.length-1]&0x0F)==0x0F)) {
        String help=ByteArrayUtils.toString(pan);
        concat = "0" + help.substring(0, help.length()-1) + ByteArrayUtils.toString(panSequenceNumber);
    } else {
        concat = ByteArrayUtils.toString(pan) + ByteArrayUtils.toString(panSequenceNumber);
    }
    logger.debug("Concat: " + concat);
    byte[] concatBytes=ByteArrayUtils.fromSafeString(concat);
    byte[] sha1Bytes = SwCryptUtils.sha1(concatBytes);
    String sha1=ByteArrayUtils.toString(sha1Bytes);
    logger.debug("X: " + sha1);
    StringBuilder b1 = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder b2 = new StringBuilder();
    for(char c : sha1.toCharArray()) {
        if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
            b1.append(c);
        } else {
            b2.append((char)(c-('A'-'0')));
        }
    }
    String y = b1.toString() + b2.toString();
    logger.debug("Y': " + y);
    y = y.substring(0, 16);
    logger.debug("Y: " + y);
    byte[] yBytes = ByteArrayUtils.fromSafeString(y);
    byte[] leftBytes = SwCryptUtils.desEncryptEcb(issuerMasterKey, yBytes);
    String left = ByteArrayUtils.toString(leftBytes);
    logger.debug("Z_{L}': " + left);
    byte[] yXorBytes = yBytes.clone();
    for (int i = 0; i < yXorBytes.length; i++) {
        yXorBytes[i]^=0xFF;
    }
    logger.debug("Y_{xor}': " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(yXorBytes));
    byte[] rightBytes = SwCryptUtils.desEncryptEcb(issuerMasterKey, yXorBytes);
    String right = ByteArrayUtils.toString(rightBytes);
    logger.debug("Z_{R}': " + right);
    String result=left+right;
    logger.debug("MK:" + result);
    return ByteArrayUtils.fromSafeString(result);
}

public static byte[] deriveCommonSessionKey(byte[] masterKey, byte[] atc) {
    byte[] rBytes=Arrays.copyOf(atc, 8);
    logger.debug("R: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(rBytes));
    byte[] f1Bytes=rBytes.clone();
    f1Bytes[2]=(byte)0xF0;
    logger.debug("F1: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(f1Bytes));
    byte[] f2Bytes=rBytes.clone();
    f2Bytes[2]=(byte)0x0F;
    logger.debug("F2: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(f2Bytes));
    byte[] f1EncBytes = SwCryptUtils.desEncryptEcb(masterKey, f1Bytes);
    logger.debug("ENC(F1): " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(f1EncBytes));
    byte[] f2EncBytes = SwCryptUtils.desEncryptEcb(masterKey, f2Bytes);
    logger.debug("ENC(F2): " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(f2EncBytes));
    byte[] result = ArrayUtils.addAll(f1EncBytes, f2EncBytes);
    logger.debug("SK: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(result));
    return result;
}

public static byte[] generateApplicationCryptogram(byte[] sessionKey, byte[] terminalData, byte[] iccData) {
    byte[] dataBytes = ArrayUtils.addAll(terminalData, iccData);
    logger.debug("DATA: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(dataBytes));
    byte[] paddedDataBytes = ArrayUtils.add(dataBytes, (byte)0x80);
    paddedDataBytes=Arrays.copyOf(paddedDataBytes, ((paddedDataBytes.length+7)/8)*8);
    logger.debug("PADDED DATA: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(paddedDataBytes));

    byte[] skBytes=sessionKey;
    byte[] skL = Arrays.copyOf(skBytes, 8);
    logger.debug("SK_{L}: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(skL));
    byte[] skR = Arrays.copyOfRange(skBytes, 8, 16);
    logger.debug("SK_{R}: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(skR));

    byte[] pom = SwCryptUtils.desEncryptCbcZeroIv(skL, paddedDataBytes);
    logger.debug("POM: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(pom));
    pom=Arrays.copyOfRange(pom, pom.length-8, pom.length);
    logger.debug("POM: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(pom));
    pom=SwCryptUtils.desDecryptEcb(skR, pom);
    logger.debug("POM: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(pom));
    pom=SwCryptUtils.desEncryptEcb(skL, pom);
    logger.debug("POM: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(pom));
    logger.debug("AC: " + ByteArrayUtils.toString(pom));
    return pom;
}
```

---

A very good source of information is the [EFTlab website](https://eftlab.co.uk/index.php) (their [BP-CCalc](https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/babylon-payments-tools/cryptographic-calculator-bp-ccalc) tool can used to compute keys, cryptograms...).

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @vlp , first of all, thank you very much !
I´ve followed your guidelines and I could get ARQC done. I had to make some changes for generating MDK, because my PAN is equal to 16 digits long, so I didn´t have to use SHA-1 (option B). I used option A instead.
The other alteration I did for SessionKey generation; as my key = 8n I calculated SK = ALG (MK) [ R ], instead of applying DES twice as you did.
Then, to generate the cryptogram I used ECB mode instead of using CBC mode, and voilá I rightly get ARQC done !
Thanks !